# Receive/Change values from running applications

Tags: c#, api, hex, hook

I found two addresses (f.i. 43BE7E61) using Cheat Engine. How do I make c# access a running app's addresses to determine/change the value that is there? I need a function like

```
int value_at_address(string address, <some type> object)
```

after having called something like

```
<some type> inject_into_app(string path);
```

which gives me the object to work with by using

```
<some type> object = new <some type> inject_into_app(string path);
```

Comment: This would be much easier to implement in unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

See this post.

http://www.mpgh.net/forum/250-c-programming/298510-c-writeprocessmemory-readprocessmemory.html